# React Proptypes union type Breakpoint gives error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-proptypes, union-types

I am having trouble giving the right proptype to the material-ui `Breakpoint` type.

The breakpoint is as follows: `export type Breakpoint = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl';`

In my App.tsx if have the following code:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Breakpoint } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints'
import withWidth from '@material-ui/core/withWidth'

interface IApp {
  width: Breakpoint
}

const App: FC<IApp> = ({ width }) => {
    // Code here
}

App.propTypes = {
  width: PropTypes.oneOf(['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl']).isRequired,
}

export default withWidth()(App)
```

Which is giving me the following error:

```
Type '{ width: Validator<string>; }' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<IApp>'.
  Types of property 'width' are incompatible.
    Type 'Validator<string>' is not assignable to type 'Validator<Breakpoint>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Breakpoint'.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Is `Breakpoint` an enum? Would you mind inlining its definition?

Comment: `export type Breakpoint = 'xs' | 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' | 'xl'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

When you do this:

```
App.propTypes = {
  width: PropTypes.oneOf(['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl']).isRequired,
}
```

TypeScript will treat `['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl']` as an array of random strings, not the specific strings you are interested in.

**Solution (TypeScript 3.4+)**

To narrow their types down to the specific values defined by `Breakpoint`, use a [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```
App.propTypes = {
  width: PropTypes.oneOf(['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'] as const).isRequired,
}
```

**Solution (TypeScript <3.4)**

If you're running a version of TypeScript older than 3.4, you can achieve the same result by creating an array of well-known string literals before you define your `propTypes`.

```
const breakpoints: Breakpoint[] = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'];

App.propTypes = {
  width: PropTypes.oneOf(breakpoints).isRequired,
}
```